# Would like to display random reviews if product has no reviews

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I'm using easydigitaldownloads to sell digital products. I combine it with [WP Customer Reviews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/) to show product reviews.

I need to use an IF statement to display the reviews. So I used `print_r($post)` to see how many reviews the download has but I couldn't see it in the post object.

How do I access the reviews or how do I display it with a conditional function?

```
If(reviews){
show specific download reviews
} else {
show generic reviews from other downloads
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Showing so-called "generic reviews" looks pretty misleading from a user's point a view...

Comment: I'm planning on writing something like: 'There are no reviews yet to this product but here are reviews from other products'